# Protect a site from stealing cookies

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I would like to secure the session more in Symfony application, so I would like add User-Agent checking.

I want to protect my site from stealing cookies.

How can I make it? In documentation I can find how to make authorization etc, but there is nothing about regenerate user from cookie.

Comment: you should encode your cookies using an encryption key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are public. You should avoid adding sensible information in. Save the data in a database or everything else than cookies

Comment: But still other user can steal cookie and use it on own computer.